# Matlab: find and replace missing value in a 1*1 struct with 34 fields

Tags: matlab, struct, nan

In Matlab, I have a `1*1` struct with 34 fields. every field is a 3d array by itself. A picture of it attached below. 
I want to have a code to find `-9.969209968386869e+36` in **everywhere of this struct** and replace it with `NaN`.
[here is a picture of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASuC6.jpg)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be less memory intensive than a cell conversion:

If your struct is called `x`,

```
names = fieldnames(x); % gets the names of the items in the struct
for i = 1:numel(names)
    x.(names{i})(x.(names{i})==-9.969209968386869e+36) = nan('single');
end
```

Comment: Dear @Dr. X this code leading to the following error:

`Error using fieldnames
Invalid input argument of type 'cell'. Input must be a structure or a
Java or COM object. `

Comment: @Behzad: `x` is supposed to be the struct that you talk about in the question. Change `x` for whatever your variable name is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
x = struct2cell(mystruct);
for i=1:34
   x{i}(x{i} == -9.969209968386869e+36)= nan
end
mystruct = cell2struct(x, fieldnames(x));
```

Comment: Thank you, this leading me following error:
`Out of memory. Type "help memory" for your options. `
do you know how to fix it?

Comment: This code works. For memory management please see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html

Comment: @Behzad your struct is 23GB. Its likely that most operations you do will double this ammount, e.g. this answer will make a copy of those 23GB. I suggest you consider carefully how you want to handle this data, as its too big, and having it in structs and operating with all of it at once will lead to countless of `out of memory` errors